# How I get users which are created by Auth::user

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two table users and customer_details. I want to get users which are created by Auth::user(). The created_by column is in customer_details table.

**User Table**

```
|  id  |  name     |      email      |  status  |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|  1   |   Admin   | admin@email.com |  Active  |
|  2   | Customer  | user@email.com  |  Active  |
```

**CustomerDetails Table**

```
|  id  |  user_id  |  added_by  |  address  |
|-------------------------------------------|
|  1   |     2     |     1      |  NY City  |
```

This is my query

```
$customers = User::role('Customer')->whereIn('status', ['Active'])->get();
```

Want to get records where added_by is current auth user

Comment: do you have the relationship defined in your models?

Comment: @apokryfos Yes I have defined the relations

Comment: Then you can probably use [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: whereHas on User?

Comment: It should work on either direction e.g. `CustomerDetail::whereHas('addedBy', function ($q) { return $q->where('id', Auth::id()); })` for your particular use case (`addedBy` is what I assumed is what you named the relationship but you should substitute that with what you actually named the relationship function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a relation in your `CustomerDetail` model:

```php
public function addedBy()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'added_by');
}
```

Then, you can query using this relation:

```php
CustomerDetail::whereHas('addedBy', function($query) {
    return $query->where('id', auth()->id());
})->get();
```

This query returns all customer created by the user current logged in.

To get all users with it's customers created by the current logged in user, add a new relation, now to the user model:

```php
public function customerDetail()
{
    return $this->hasOne(CustomerDetail::class, 'added_by');
}
```

and query users with customers created byt the logged in user:

```php
User::role('Customer')->whereHas('customerDetail', function($query) {
  return $query->where('added_by', auth()->id());
})
->whereIn('status', ['Active'])
->get();
```

Comment: It getting me record from customer_details table. I want from user table

Comment: @IhtishamKhan so you want Users which has a customer added by the current logged in user?

Comment: @IhtishamKhan check the answer again, i added the query to get all users with customers created by the current logged in user.

Comment: No what I want is all users with role customer, which is created be logged in user,

Comment: So my answer is correct, just forgot to add the role scope and the wherein for the status.

Answer (score 2):

`$customers = User::role('Customer')->whereIn('added_by', Auth::id())->get();`

I think this should help

here we are using `Auth::id()` to get the id of the current user and then using eloquent to search for it.

I am considering that here added_by column contains the ID;

Comment: added_by is not in user table

Comment: Then must-have a relation as mentioned by @Pratik or you can add it as a column in users table